# Importing CSV files from a directory into R

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to import a directory of daily crime statistics into R. My data files do not have headers and when I import the CSV files into R its makes the first row of the dataset the header. I have tried `col_names = FALSE` but I am receiving an error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
folder <- "/Users/myname/Desktop/Stats 408/folder/"     
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv")

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i], 
  read.csv((paste(folder, file_list[i], sep='')))
)}
```

Comment: Try `read.table()` rather than `read.csv`.

Comment: Include ``header = FALSE`` in ``read.csv``

Comment: i've tried to use that but I have not been successful. I might be putting it in the incorrect location, where would you suggest placing it?

Comment: FYI `paste(..., sep='')` can be written more concisely as `paste0(...)`

Comment: Please, read the help text `?read.csv` where you'll find an explanation of the `header` parameter.

Comment: Are you able to transfer your data in .csv  to an Excel file (.xlsx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally prefer to import data like this into a list, since it tends to clutter up the workspace less than using assign (and it's less of a nuisance if you have files with strange names).

```
setNames(lapply(file_list, function(fname){
  read.csv(paste0(folder, fname), header=F)
}), file_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `read.table` function? I'm completely new to R, so I'm sure I won't be of any great help, but I've gotten used to using the `read.table` function with `header=FALSE` if there are no headers.